# Discord ping command

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I tried to use the following ping command, but when I trigger it it gives me the following error:

The code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    let waiting = await message.channel.send("Pinging :hourglass:...").catch(console.error);
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

    .setTitle("Dragonite's & API's Latency", bot.user.avatarURL)
    .setColor("#f900ff")
    .addField("Dragonite :", `${waiting.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp}` + "ms`", true)
    .addField("API :", Math.round(bot.ping) + "ms", true)
    .addFooter("Dragonite | Requested by " + message.author.tag)

    waiting.edit(embed).catch(console.error);
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "ping",
    description: "Calculate Dragonite's & API's Latency.",
    usage: "ping",
    example: "ping"
}
```

The error:
`(node:23760) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: (intermediate value).setTitle(...).setColor(...).addField(...).addField(...).addFooter is not a function`

Comment: typo, change `addFooter` to [`setFooter`](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#using-the-richembedmessageembed-constructor)

Answer (score 0):

There was a typo in your code, that should fix it:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
 let waiting = await message.channel
  .send('Pinging :hourglass:...')
  .catch(console.error);
 let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

  .setTitle("Dragonite's & API's Latency", bot.user.avatarURL)
  .setColor('#f900ff')
  .addField(
   'Dragonite :',
   `${waiting.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp}` + 'ms`',
   true
  )
  .addField('API :', Math.round(bot.ping) + 'ms', true)
  .setFooter('Dragonite | Requested by ' + message.author.tag);

 waiting.edit(embed).catch(console.error);
};

module.exports.help = {
 name: 'ping',
 description: "Calculate Dragonite's & API's Latency.",
 usage: 'ping',
 example: 'ping',
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`addFooter()` is not a function, as there cannot be more than one footer. Instead, use [`setFooter()`](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#using-the-richembedmessageembed-constructor).